# Angular ui-router doesnt resolve and work properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, state.go

While using ui-router i tried for resolve , is there any accesstoken in localstorage , if so proceed to state 'home' else state 'login'. But the program doesnt run as desired, if there is no accesstoken and i hit url for my view page, it shows blank page(i think my view page) not loading login.

here is the part

```
     $stateProvider
    .state("home", {
        url: "/home",
        templateUrl: "home.html",
        resolve: {
            "check": function() {
                console.log("/home");

                if (localStorage.getItem("accessToken") == null) {
                    console.log("main check");

                    $state.go("login");
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .state("login", {
        url: "/login",
        templateUrl: "loginpage.html",
        resolve: {
            "check": function() {
                console.log("/login");

                if (localStorage.getItem("accessToken") != null) {
                    console.log("log check");

                    $state.go("home");
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .state("otherwise", {
        url: "*path",
        templateUrl: "loginpage.html",
        resolve: {
            "check": function() {
                console.log("/login");

                if (localStorage.getItem("accessToken") != null) {
                    console.log("log check");

                    $state.go("home");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

console prints "log check" but shows no page...
please help

Comment: `resolve` is probably wrong place to do your check. You might want to try with `onEnter` callback of `.state`

Comment: thanks.. lemme check that